# Search through excel document for specific word- add following data to data table

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I come with questions regarding working with excel programatically.

The excel document is structured as such. The data doesn't actually look like this but the structure is very similar

```
Animal       Legs      Color    Weight
Bear         4         Brown    500lbs
Ox           4         Black    1300lbs
Human        2         Light    170lbs
       The list can go on...
```

However there is always the possibility there is more data underneath the first set of data- with the same exact structure. Resulting in something that looks like:

```
Animal       Legs      Color    Weight
Bear         4         Brown    500lbs
Ox           4         Black    1300lbs
Human        2         Light    170lbs




Animal      Legs       Color    Weight
Blue Crab   6          Blue     0.7lbs
Snake       0          Grey     8oz
Chimpanzee  2          Black    80lbs
Anaconda    0          Green    500lbs
```

There is other data on this single worksheet, but I would only want to capture this data. Let's say that the only constant of this worksheet is the structure. The actual tables could start on any row, any column, and no this data cannot be grouped in excel.

What I was thinking is programatically searching for the word "Animal". When "Animal" is found, get the location of it (EX: "A2"), and from there begin assigning the table headers relative to where the "Animal" cell is located. Once that is done, begin populating data from ranges directly underneath the "Animal" cell all the way the last row/cell of that respective table. IF there is another set of data, append that data to the already existing data table.

As always when I ask a question on SO, there is probably a way better method of doing this.

1.) Search "Animal" in C#

2.) When "Animal" found, assign table headers from cells to the right of it

3.) Populate table with data under these headers.

4.) If there is another set of data, i.e. if another "Animal" found, put the data underneath those headers into the same data table.

My research includes various failed attempts at customizing other people's codes, mainly this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx. Right now I am still working on the "searching" part.

Comment: Well, the tables won't be somewhere absolutely ridiculous. I was just trying to make a point that they won't always be on the same exact cell, but not far off.

Comment: Actually looked at the link, deleted prior comment.  Using find would work fairly well actually.  You would have to loop using Find and FindNext until FindNext returned a null.  The return value is a range, which has an associated CellID with it, and you can use the algorithm you came up with for that.  There may be a better way to do it, but the algorithm is sound.